# ListView with ImageView from URL and TextView not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I've made a ListView with a custom adapter where I want to load an ImageView from URL along with some hard-coded text.

However my code doesn't work. **It loads the list with all the texts, but the images are blank**.
I've managed to load a single ImageView, but when using multiple in a ListView it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

My code :

`AdItem.java`

```
public class AdItem {

    private ImageView adImage;
    private String adImageURL;
    private String adTitle;
    private String adPrice;
    private String adSize;
    private String adDetails;
    private String adMessage;
    private String adFavorite;

    // getters and setters here

}
```

`SearchResultFragment.java`

```
public class SearchResultFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_searchresult, container, false);

        ArrayList image_details = getListData();
        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResult);
        lv1.setAdapter(new SearchResultAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), image_details));

        return view;
    }

    private ArrayList getListData() {

        ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
        AdItem adData = new AdItem();

        adData.setAdImageURL("http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg");
        adData.setAdTitle("Apartment");
        adData.setAdPrice("300");
        adData.setAdSize("40m");
        adData.setAdDetails("This is a wonderful apartment at a reasonable price.");
        results.add(adData);

        adData = new AdItem();
        adData.setAdImageURL("http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg");
        adData.setAdTitle("Apartment");
        adData.setAdPrice("400");
        adData.setAdSize("40m");
        adData.setAdDetails("This is a wonderful apartment at a reasonable price.");
        results.add(adData);

        adData = new AdItem();
        adData.setAdImageURL("http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg");
        adData.setAdTitle("Apartment");
        adData.setAdPrice("500");
        adData.setAdSize("40m");
        adData.setAdDetails("This is a wonderful apartment at a reasonable price.");
        results.add(adData);

        return results;
    }

}
```

`SearchResultAdapter.java`

```
public class SearchResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SearchResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.searchresult_single_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.adImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adImage);
            holder.adTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adTitle);
            holder.adPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adPrice);
            holder.adSize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adSize);
            holder.adDetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adDetails);
            holder.adMessage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adMessage);
            holder.adFavorite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adFavorite);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        AdItem adListItem = (AdItem) listData.get(position);

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(layoutInflater.getContext());
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(adListItem.getAdImageURL(), holder.adImage);

        holder.adTitle.setText(adListItem.getAdTitle());
        holder.adPrice.setText(adListItem.getAdPrice());
        holder.adSize.setText(adListItem.getAdSize());
        holder.adDetails.setText(adListItem.getAdDetails());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView adImage;
        TextView adTitle;
        TextView adPrice;
        TextView adSize;
        TextView adDetails;
        ImageView adMessage;
        ImageView adFavorite;
    }

}
```

Sources :
http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are downloading Image from url, so I am suggesting you to use Android Query for this, you will never get this error if you used it.

AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);

As an example to load image directly from url:

androidAQuery.id(ucover).image(user_pro, true, true);